# Verify that $\sum^{8564}_{i=82} \binom{8564}{i} < 2^{8564}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

I have to tell if the following inequality is true: $$\sum^{8564}_{i=82} \binom{8564}{i} < 2^{8564}$$

but how do I tackle that? I reckon the *standard* formula for calculate the value of the binomial coefficient is kind of useless in this case, the summation startles me. I feel really stuck, can anyone please throw any hint at me?

Comment: I believe the standard term is *inequality* instead of *disequation*. Am I the only one who has never heard of a disequation before?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I got the word wrong because of my native language. Editing right now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that 
$$2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $$2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i\end{pmatrix} 1^i 1^{n-i}$$

Answer (score 4):

Use the very well known, textbook identity 
$$\sum_0^n \tbinom{n}{k} = (1+1)^n = 2^n $$
Can you show that your LHS is strictly smaller than the LHS of the above equation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You don't need to calculate anything explicitly. What is the formula for $(1+x)^n$?